# Haskell: example of function of type a -> a, besides the identity

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, type-variables

I've just started playing a little with Haskell... I want to write a function of the same type of the identity. Obviously, not equivalent to it. That would be something like,

`myfunction :: a -> a`

I cannot come up with an example in which the parameter and the return type are the same and can be virtually anything (this excludes the possibility of using Haskell's Typeclasses).

Comment: `myfunction _ = undefined` is pretty much the only other possible function with that type signature.

Comment: In that case, myfunction has type a -> b, which is not exactly what was looking for. But thanks anyway, its interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, `a -> b` it's most general signature, but you can restrict it to `a -> a`.

Comment: On the same topic, see the related questions [ML function of type 'a -> 'b](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/302/ml-function-of-type-a-b) and [ML functions from polymorphic lists to polymorphic lists](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/341/ml-functions-from-polymorphic-lists-to-polymorphic-lists) on [cs.se].

Comment: @dbaupp: I can see a third possible function: `f x = seq x x`.

Comment: @CesarB, `seq` doesn't really count... it is a magic compiler incantation, that doesn't really fit into the type system. (Granted that that function does have type `a -> a`, and so does `f x = seq b x` where `b` is any non-bottom, non-`undefined` value, e.g. `f x = seq [1..10] x`.)

Comment: @dbaupp: `f x = seq x x` is special because it is strict in `x`, unlike `f x = id x` which AFAIK is not. `f x = seq b x` is more like `f x = id x` in this case, it is the `seq x x` which is special. So I see three different functions, without playing with `unsafe` things: const bottom (`f x = const undefined x`), lazy identity (`f x = id x`), and strict identity (`f x = seq x x`).

Comment: @CesarB, `seq x x` isn't strict in `x`, see [the last sentence of the second paragraph](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Seq).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is impossible without using `undefined` as another commenter mentioned.  Let's prove it by counter-example.  Assume there were such a function:

```
f :: a -> a
```

When you say that's it not the same as `id`, that implies that you cannot define:

```
f x = x
```

However, consider the case where `a` is the type `()`:

```
f () = ...
```

The only possible result `f` could return would be `()`, but that would be the same implementation as `id`, therefore a contradiction.

The more sophisticated and rigorous answer is to show that the type `a -> a` must be isomorphic to `()`.  When we say two types `a` and `b` are isomorphic, that means that we can define two functions:

```
fw :: a -> b
bw :: b -> a
```

... such that:

```
fw . bw = id
bw . fw = id
```

We can easily do this when the first type is `a -> a` and the second type is `()`:

```
fw :: (forall a . a -> a) -> ()
fw f = f ()

bw :: () -> (forall a . a -> a)
bw () x = x
```

We can then prove that:

```
fw . bw
= \() -> fw (bw ())
= \() -> fw (\x -> x)
= \() -> (\x -> x) ()
= \() -> ()
= id

bw . fw
= \f -> bw (fw f)
-- For this to type-check, the type of (fw f) must be ()
-- Therefore, f must be `id`
= \f -> id
= \f -> f
= id
```

When you prove two types are isomorphic, one thing you know is that if one type is inhabited by a finite number of elements, so must the other one.  Since the type `()` is inhabited by exactly one value:

```
data () = ()
```

That means that the type `(forall a . a -> a)` must also be inhabited by exactly one value, which just so happens to be the implementation for `id`.

Edit: Some people have commented that the proof of the isomorphism is not sufficiently rigorous, so I'll invoke the Yoneda lemma, which when translated into Haskell, says that for any functor `f`:

```
(forall b . (a -> b) -> f b) ~ f a
```

Where `~` means that `(forall b . (a -> b) -> f b)` is isomorphic to `f a`.  If you choose the `Identity` functor, this simplifies to:

```
(forall b . (a -> b) -> b) ~ a
```

... and if you choose `a = ()`, this further simplifies to:

```
(forall b . (() -> b) -> b) ~ ()
```

You can easily prove that `() -> b` is isomorphic to `b`:

```
fw :: (() -> b) -> b
fw f = f ()

bw :: b -> (() -> b)
bw b = \() -> b

fw . bw
= \b -> fw (bw b)
= \b -> fw (\() -> b)
= \b -> (\() -> b) ()
= \b -> b
= id

bw . fw
= \f -> bw (fw f)
= \f -> bw (f ())
= \f -> \() -> f ()
= \f -> f
= id
```

So we can then use that to finally specialize the Yoneda isomorphism to:

```
(forall b . b -> b) ~ ()
```

Which says that any function of type `forall b . b -> b` is isomorphic to `()`.  The Yoneda lemma provides the rigor that my proof was missing.

Comment: You did reduce the problem of how many functions of type `(forall a . a -> a)` there are to how many functions of type `() -> ()` there are. In your proof of `fw . bw = id`, for the second to last equality, you assume that there is only one.

But is there only one `() -> ()`? Only if you ignore strictness issues, otherwise "f _ = ()" and "f () = ()" are different functions!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm on board with the (it seems, hidden) assumption that "`f` is `id` at type `()`" implies "`f` is `id` at all types". I think this happens to be true in Haskell -- and the generalization of this property is called parametricity -- but proving it looks significantly harder than the proof you did!

Comment: @DanielWagner I agree, the proof is wrong. The step “Therefore, f must be `id`” makes no sense: that's what we're trying to prove! A proof must enumerate all the possible terms of Haskell in some way, since “Haskell is parametric” could be otherwise (informally) stated as “Haskell doesn't have typecase”.

Comment: @DanielWagner If I were being more rigorous I would just cite the Yoneda Lemma for proof.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez If you add typecase to the language, there are many more functions of type `forall a. a->a`. Where would your proof break?

Comment: The first part of the proof ending _.. therefore a contradiction._ is flawed. You only prove that there is no other function of '() -> ()` except the identity. But this itself doesn't prove that there is a function `f :: a -> a` that isn't the identity on some other type - you only prove that `f ()` must be `()`. (Otherwise I agree there is no such function, just that your argument doesn't prove it.)

Comment: @PetrPudlák The first part was intended to be non-rigorous and to give an intuition for why the second proof worked, although I could have mentioned something like "The shape of the only solution is similar to the shape of `id`" and tie in the notion of parametricity.  Like I said, the rigorous proof is to simply invoke the Yoneda Lemma to prove the isomorphism.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I see. Still I think this non-rigorous part actually misleads. Anyhow, I'd be interested in the rigorous proof using Yoneda lemma (I believe others too). I'm not that well-versed in category and this would be certainly beneficial for many people.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Alright, I updated it to show the proof using the Yoneda lemma and explained what the Yoneda lemma says and how it translates to that specific isomorphism.

Comment: You use that `\() -> f ()` is equal to `f`, but for `f = const ()`, they differ on an non-convergent argument. But I guess your answer ignores all issues related to termination, right?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Correct.  If you admit non-termination, then there is another function that has type `a -> a`, which is `f = f`

Answer (score 12):

Let me formulate an answer that elaborates on dbaupp’s comment. Any function of type `a -> a` would also give rise to an function of type `() -> ()`, so I will look at this subproblem first.

A usual semantics of Haskell types and functions would represent a type as a pointed chain-complete partial order, and functions as continuous functions. The type `()` is represented by the two element set *{⊥,()}* with the order *⊥⊏()*. In plain set theory, there are 2^2=4 functions from this set onto itself, but only three of them are continuous:

- f1: ⊥ ↦ ⊥, () ↦ ⊥,
- f2: ⊥ ↦ ⊥, () ↦ (), and
- f3: ⊥ ↦ (), () ↦ ().

So in our semantic model, there are three different functions of type `() -> ()`. But which of them can be implemented in Haskell? All of them!

- `f1 _ = undefined` (or `f1 x = f1 x`)
- `f2 x = x` (or `f2 = id`)
- `f3 _ = ()` (or `f3 = const ()`)

Looking at these definitions, you can see that `f1` and `f2` can also be used to define a function of type `a -> a`. As they do different things already on `()`, they are different. So we have at least two different functions of type `a -> a`.

In the above semantic model, there are many more functions of type `a -> a`, but these would not be expressible in Haskell (this is related to parametricity and Wadler’s [Theorems for Free](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/free/free.ps)). A proper proof that `f1` and `f2` are the only such functions does not seem to be very easy, as it depends on what the Haskell language disallows (e.g. no pattern matching on the type of the argument).

Comment: BTW, proper math support in stack overflow would be nice.

Comment: There's [cs.se] for that… Which reminds me, [ML functions from polymorphic lists to polymorphic lists](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/341/ml-functions-from-polymorphic-lists-to-polymorphic-lists) needs a better answer.

Comment: We can reasonably easy prove that a function of type `a -> a` has to be the identity function by using a proof by contradiction. The free theorem for `f :: a -> a` states that for all `g :: t1 -> t2` and all `x :: t1` we have `g (f x) = f (g x)`. We can assume that `f` is not the identity. Then there will be a type `t` and an argument `y :: t` such that `f y /= y`. Then we define `g :: t -> t` with `g x = if x == f y then y else x`. We get `g (f y) = y` and `f (g y) = f y` and by the free theorem these are equal, which is a contradiction to the assumption.

Answer (score 9):

Unless you are willing to use undefined or bottom (a non-terminating expression), there literally are no other functions that satisfy that type.

This is one of the large strengths of the Haskell type system. It's possible to strongly limit possible functions that can pass trough a compiler into the ones that are obviously correct. For an extreme example, see [djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/djinn-th/0.0.1/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Djinn.html) -- it takes a type, and generates possible functions that match that type. Even for real, complex examples, the list is often very short.

Comment: This is why it is occasionally said that any expression which typechecks is doing something useful, even if you're not sure what. For sufficiently polymorphic types, like those Djinn handles well, this is not far from the truth!

Comment: Or if you're willing to use `unsafePerformIO`: `trace "Hi" :: a -> a`

Answer (score 8):

The key here is to understand that we know *nothing* about `a`, especially we have no way to generate a new one or to transform it to something different. Hence we have no choice as returning it (or the bottom value). As soon as we have *more information* about `a` (e.g. a context bound), we can do more interesting things with it:

```
f :: Monoid a => a -> a
f _ = mempty
```

or

```
f :: Monoid a => a -> a
f x = x `mappend` x `mappend` x
```

Or if you have the choice like in `f :: (a, a) -> a`, you have two possible implementations (ignoring the bottom values again), but for `f :: (a, b) -> a` you are back to one implementation, which is the same as for `fst`: While it is valid to call `f` with a pair of identical types, e.g. `f ("x", "y")`, you can be sure that `f` behaves like `fst`, because in the implementation of `f` you have no way to test if both argument types might be the same. Similarly, there is only one non-bottom version of `f :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`.

Polymorphism limits the degrees of freedom, because you don't know anything about your arguments, and in some cases it boils down to one non-bottom version.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, no such other *total* function can exist. (If we don't limit ourselves to total functions then we can inhabit any type by `undefined`.)

I'll try to give a theoretical explanation based on the λ-calculus:

For simplicity, let's limit ourselves to λ-terms (to which we can translate any Haskell expression). For a λ-term `M` let's call `A` its *head* if `M ≡ A N1 ... Nk` and `A` isn't an application (`k` can be also zero). Note that if `M` is in [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Normal_forms_and_confluence) then `A` cannot be a λ-abstraction unless `k = 0`.

So let `M :: a -> a` be a λ-term in normal form. Since we have no variables in the context, `M` cannot be a variable and it cannot be an application. If it were, its head would have to be a variable. So `M` must be a λ-abstraction, it must be `M ≡ λ(x:a).N`.

Now `N` must be of type `a`, formally `{x:a}⊢N:a`. If `N` was a λ-abstraction, its type would be `σ -> τ`, which is not possible. If `N` was a function application then it's head would have to be a variable, and the only one we have in the context is `x`. But since `x:a`, we cannot apply `x` to anything, `x P` isn't tapeable for any P. So the only possibility is that `N ≡ x`. So, `M` must be `λ(x:a).x`.

<sub>(Please correct my English, if possible. In particular, I'm not sure how to use the [subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) right).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Here's one:

```
Prelude> t = \x -> (\y -> y) x
Prelude> :t t
t :: p -> p
Prelude> t 3
3
Prelude> t "hello"
"hello"
```