# Haskell: expression of "generic" type

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, variable-types

In a similar problem as the one showed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230820/haskell-example-of-function-of-type-a-a-same-as-the-identity), is it possible to have a Haskell expression of "generic" type a? Something like,

`myExpression :: a`

I'm new to Haskell, but from what i've been seeing this cannot be achieved.

Comment: A better question might be "why would you want to do this?" It might be useful in an object-oriented language, but in Haskell it wouldn't be very useful at all.

Comment: At that moment i was just curious about whether that could be achieved or not, but now i can really (begin to) see the usefulness of the bottom expression and it's relation to partial functions, strict and non-strict functions and evaluation strategy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is nothing that satisfies that other than bottom, e.g.

```
myExpression = myExpression

-- or,

myExpression = undefined
```

---

Is there any reasonable way that it *could* be possible? Some non-bottom expression that is both an `Integer` and of type `Maybe (String -> IO ())` (for example).

---

Furthermore, given [the question you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230820/haskell-example-of-function-of-type-a-a-same-as-the-identity), one answer of which proved that the only non-bottom function with type signature `a -> a` is `id`, we have a proof that there can't be a non-bottom expression with type `a`. If there was, then

```
f _ = myExpression
```

could have type `a -> a`, and this is neither `id` nor bottom, i.e. a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You can read that type signature as "for all types **a**, myExpression is of type **a**".  That means myExpression must be some value that exists in all types.

Mathematically speaking, no such value exists, since **a** could be "Badgers" or "Things that are not badgers", and these two sets are necessarily distinct.

In the Haskell type system, the only valid value for myExpression to take is **undefined**, aka bottom.

Answer (score 1):

While abstractly there is only one value that has type "a", bottom, there are a variety of possible interpretations at runtime.

```
myExpression = myExpression
```

This will never terminate.

```
myExpression = undefined
```

This will (when using GHC) print "*** Exception: Prelude.undefined"

```
myExpression = error "Hello!
```

This will print "*** Exception: Hello!"

```
myExpression = unsafePerformIO (launchNukes >> fail "BOOM")
```

The behavior of this version of bottom depends on which libraries you've imported.

Since you ask about a "generic" type, you might mean the type of things that can usefully contain any value.  In that case, take a look at [Data.Dynamic](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html), which allows you to convert anything that has an in-memory representation to a value of type "Dynamic".  Later, when consuming a value of type "Dynamic", you can attempt to turn it into a more specific type that you can actually do something useful with.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while turning things into `Dynamic` and back again is possible, it's far from advisable, _especially_ for beginners. @acrespo: The type `a` stands for any type you like, so if you have a function `a -> Bool`, you can use it on anything, but if it's of type `Num a => a -> Bool`, you can use it on any type that's a `Num`eric type. Thus `a` means "any type you like" - you don't need to find something of type `a` to use this function. Make sure you study the types and type classes chapter of _Learn You a Haskell for Great Good_, http://learnyouahaskell.com/.