# How do I show that a Haskell type is inhabited by one and only one function?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, type-theory

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230918/257418), Gabriel Gonzalez shows how to show that `id` is the only inhabitant of `forall a. a -> a`. To do so (in the most formal iteration of the proof), he shows that the type is isomorphic to `()` using the [Yoneda lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma), and since `()` has only one value in it, so must the type of `id`. Summarized, his proof is like this:

> Yoneda says:
>
> ```
> Functor f => (forall b . (a -> b) -> f b) ~ f a
> ```
>
> If `a = ()` and `f = Identity`, this becomes:
>
> ```
> (forall b. (() -> b) -> b) ~ ()
> ```
>
> And since trivially `() -> b ~ b`, the LHS is basically the type of `id`.

This feels like a bit of a "magic trick" that works well for `id`. I'm trying to do the same thing for a more complex function type:

```
(b -> a) -> (a -> b -> c) -> b -> c
```

but I have no idea where to start. I know it is inhabited by `\f g x = g (f x) x`, and if you ignore ugly `⊥`/`undefined` stuff, I'm pretty sure there are no other functions of this type.

I don't think Gabriel's trick will *immediately* apply here whichever way I pick the types. Are there other approaches (that are equally formal!) with which I can show the isomorphism between this type and `()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can apply [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus).

Short example, with type `a -> a`, we could construct term like: `\x -> (\y -> y) x`, but that still normalises to `\x -> x` which is `id`. In sequent calculus the system prohibites from constructing "reducable" proofs.

Your type is `(b -> a) -> (a -> b -> c) -> b -> c`, informally:

```
f: b -> a
g: a -> b -> c
x: b
--------------
Goal: c
```

And there aren't many ways to proceed:

```
apply g

f: b -> a
g: a -> b -> c
x: b
---------------
Subgoal0: a
Subgoal1: b


apply f

f: b -> a
g: a -> b -> c
x: b
---------------
Subgoal0': b
Subgoal1: b


-- For both
apply x
```

So in the end, seems that `g (f x) x` is the only inhabitant of that type.

---

Yoneda lemma approach, have to be careful to actually have `forall x`!

```
 (b -> a) -> (a -> b -> c) -> b -> c
 forall b a. (b -> a) -> b -> forall c. (a -> b -> c) -> c
```

Let concentrate on the end:

```
 (a -> b -> c) -> c ~ ((a,b) -> c) -> c
```

That is isomorphic to `(a, b)`, so whole type reduces to

```
(b -> a) -> b -> (a, b)
```

Take `f = Compose (Reader b) (,b)`

```
(b -> a) -> f a ~ f b ~ b -> (b,b)
```

And that is unique by taking `HP a = (a,a)` functor:

```
b -> (b,b) ~ (() -> b) -> HP b ~ HP () ~ ()
```

---

*EDIT* the first approach feels a bit more hand-wavy, but feels somehow more direct: Given the restricted set of rules, how the proof can be constructed, how many proofs we can construct?

Comment: Ahh, I had thought of using currying to get `((a, b) -> c)`, but not of switching the order of arguments, somehow -- that did the trick!

Comment: You can also take `f` to be the covariant hom-functor instead of `Id`: `(a -> b -> c) -> b -> c` ~ `((a, b) -> c) -> (->) b c` ~ `b -> (a, b)`.

Comment: could you please fully parenthesize the `forall b a. (b -> a) -> b -> forall c. (a -> b -> c) -> c` type, for the scope of each `forall` to be explicitly seen?

Comment: @WillNess the scope extends to the far right, in the same way as lambda abstraction: `\a b -> .... \c -> ...`.