# Understanding function definitions and types in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types

I am trying to write a simple tool in Haskell as a learning exercise, and have encountered something that I cannot figure out. Here is a simple sample illustrating it.

```
idMap :: a -> a
idMap x = map id x

main = do
    print $ idMap [1, 2]
```

According to my understanding, this example should compile and print `[1, 2]` when run.  However, if fails to compile with the following message:

```
source_file.hs:2:18: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[b0]’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          idMap :: forall a. a -> a
        at source_file.hs:1:10
    • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: map id x
      In an equation for ‘idMap’: idMap x = map id x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a
          (bound at source_file.hs:2:7)
        idMap :: a -> a
          (bound at source_file.hs:2:1)
```

It kind of makes sense, given that the signature of `map` is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` so the input type is not necessarily the same as the output type, but the signature of `id` is `a -> a` so surely it follows that `map id` would have a signature of `(a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]`?

The second part I don't really understand is why this is an exception given that all the types (`a` and `b` as above) are `Integer`. It would make sense to me that since the signature of `idMap` is `a -> a`, there should only be a compile exception if it is used in a situation where the output type is expected to be different from input type.

Finally, how would I make this code actually work?  My real code is a little more complicated and I am relying on the output type matching the input type elsewhere in the code so I don't want to change the signature of `idMap`, I want to know what I would need to do to write a function with that signature.

Comment: The type of `map id` is `[a] -> [a]` while you specify it as `a -> a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are applying `idMap` to a list. Therefore, we know the argument type should be some list type. Further, you expect the return type to be a list (`[1,2]`), so the return type should be a list as well. Since the `id` function is fully polymorphic (`a -> a`), we can `map` it over a list of any type `a` and return a list of items of the same type `a`. Thus, your final type signature should be `[a] -> [a]`.

Regarding your second question, while it's true that the argument type and return type are both the same, the type as `a -> a` is not true **for all** types `a`. Based on the type signature of `map`, `idMap` **must** accept a list argument. We can declare type signatures for functions that are more constrained than necessary, but not less.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of `idMap`...

```
idMap x = map id x
```

... involves applying `map id` on `x`. As a consequence, `x` must be a list.

```
GHCi> :t map id
map id :: [b] -> [b]
```

This will work just fine:

```
idMap :: [a] -> [a]
idMap x = map id x
```

Note that, thanks to the use of `id`, `x` and `idMap x` do have the same type (as do their elements), as you expected.

Comment: Thanks. That does sort of make sense. But does that mean I always need to be explicit as possible with signatures?  I would have thought that `a` just means an unknown type, which happens to be a list of another unknown type?

Comment: The type signature `a -> a` means that `a` could be *any* type, but based on the type signature of `map`, this is not true. This might help you understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230820/haskell-example-of-function-of-type-a-a-besides-the-identity

Comment: @aquavitae The issue is that, as mnoronha points out, `idMap :: a -> a` amounts to stating that you are able to pass anything to your function (even, say, an `Integer` or a `Bool`), which is not true. Given how you are using `map`, `[a] -> [a]` is the most general type possible (an example of a more specialised signature that would be accepted by the type checker is `idMap :: [Integer] -> [Integer]`).